# Twitter authentication with Passport middleware in Node

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, express, passport-twitter

I'm developing a website with Node.js (using Express framework). In order to use Twitter authentication, I'm using `passport` module (http://passportjs.org), and his wrapper for Twitter called `passport-twitter`.

My server-side script is:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , keys = require('./oauth/keys')
  , TwitterStrategy = require("passport-twitter").Strategy;

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('foo'));
  app.use(express.session());
  // Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
  // persistent login sessions (recommended).
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: keys.twitterConsumerKey,
    consumerSecret: keys.twitterConsumerSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://local.host:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ twitterId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      else { return done(null, user); }
    });
  }
));

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/contacts', routes.contacts);
app.get('/cv', routes.cv);
app.get('/projects', routes.projects);
app.get('/users', user.list);

// Redirect the user to Twitter for authentication.
// When complete, Twitter will redirect the user back to the
// application at /auth/twitter/callback
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

// Twitter will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the
// authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If
// access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise,
// authentication has failed.
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('twitter',
    {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
    }
  )
);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

The URI associated to login is `http://local.host:3000/auth/twitter`; when I visit it, Twitter  shows me the authentication form for linking my account with my own website but, after this step, the following error occurs:

```
Express
500 ReferenceError: User is not defined
```

How can I solve this problem?
Best regards, Vi.

Comment: var User instead of var user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define your User type somewhere. It looks like you expect this thing `User` to exist and to have the functions `findOrCreate` and `findById`, but you never defined that anywhere. Where are you 'finding' these users? The ones that aren't found, where are they being 'created'? Are you using a database? How do you connect to the database? I think you forgot the "Model" step. You might want to take a look at [Mongoose Auth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth) which is like Passport but it plugs directly into [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), which connnects to a [Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/) Database

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a really stupid error! Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: why would you need any database when signing-in users? it's not a "must". I don't use any database in my app, I have nothing to save..

Comment: vsync you are correct, you don't NEED to have a database. Only if you want to persist user information from one request to another do you need some sort of a database (can be files, in-memory, or a proper database).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did when I faced the same error which says `User` isn't defined:

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: keys.twitterConsumerKey,
    consumerSecret: keys.twitterConsumerSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://local.host:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    done(null, profile);
  }
));
```

Comment: Please don't do this, it is not safe.  You have a single `User` instance, which is shared amongst all visitors to your site.  This will cause many security and access control problems.

Comment: but my app says the `User` is not defined. I have to manually define it. I've updated my answer by the way

Comment: Right, User is something you need to implement yourself.  It's usually a class or model provided by an ORM such as Mongoose.  The important thing is there should be a unique instance for each user of your application.

Comment: well basically my app doesn't need anything but the user name and photo, so they just login and Passport generates a cookie which I can read as long as they are connected... I don't need a DB. in ALL the examples no the internet they seem to be using this illusive `User` variable, and nowhere it says where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue when integrating the BeatsMusic OAuth2 strategy for Passport within Kraken. It looks like the examples for the various Kraken Passport integration strategies use the same simple example documentation which did not explicitly discuss the User object (understandable).

I figured out (from digging thru the passport strategy examples found @ https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-examples/tree/master/with.passport) that the User is intended to be a model based on the Mongoose model schema and also is configured with the https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate plugin.

After i included the `User = require('../PATH_TO/user')` and added this plugin to the User model, voila! no more errors :)

Sounds like you don't need the DB functionality so you are probably good with removing the auth check.

Hope this helps for anyone else having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the api is not ready for the cases not need User's db integration. My solution was ignore the `done()` function and make a redirect to the success page.

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: keys.twitterConsumerKey,
    consumerSecret: keys.twitterConsumerSecret,
    callbackURL: "http://local.host:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    //done(null, profile);
    this.redirect('/auth/success');
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

To further explain on Max's answer: "You need to Create `User` yourself"

[Read Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local#user-model)

TL:DR - Basically you have to have a userschema that you use to set users and verify users, it needs a mongoose db backend, which is actually simple to configure.

essentially creating this middleware:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        group        : String,
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    },
    twitter          : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        displayName  : String,
        username     : String
    },
    google           : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }

});

// methods ======================
// generating a hash
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```